# JBoss: Adding JMS resources to JBoss 4.3

Tags: jboss, jms

I am having trouble understanding where to define the JMS resources that are needed by the JMS queue implementation in JBoss.  Currently the code that I'm dealing with works on WebLogic, and I'm trying to migrate it over to JBoss 4.3 eap.

In weblogic, there is a jms.xml file that defines the JMS resources and JNDI lookup names.  For example:

```
<quota name="CacheT.Quota">
  <bytes-maximum>9999999999999999999</bytes-maximum>
  <messages-maximum>9999999999999999999</messages-maximum>
  <policy>FIFO</policy>
  <shared>false</shared>
</quota>
<template name="MessQ">
  <delivery-failure-params>
    <redelivery-limit>1</redelivery-limit>
    <expiration-policy>Discard</expiration-policy>
  </delivery-failure-params>
</template>
<connection-factory name="Queue Conn Fact">
  <default-targeting-enabled>true</default-targeting-enabled>
  <jndi-name>com.company.QueueConnFact</jndi-name>
  <default-delivery-params>
    <default-delivery-mode>Persistent</default-delivery-mode>
  </default-delivery-params>
  <transaction-params>
    <xa-connection-factory-enabled>false</xa-connection-factory-enabled>
  </transaction-params>
  <security-params>
    <attach-jmsx-user-id>false</attach-jmsx-user-id>
  </security-params>
</connection-factory>
<queue name="EMessQ">
  <sub-deployment-name>Product_JMS</sub-deployment-name>
  <template>MessQ</template>
  <jndi-name>com.company.EMessQ</jndi-name>
</queue>
<uniform-distributed-topic name="CacheT">
  <sub-deployment-name>Product_JMS</sub-deployment-name>
  <jndi-name>com.company.CacheT</jndi-name>
  <load-balancing-policy>Round-Robin</load-balancing-policy>
</uniform-distributed-topic>
```

For the life of me I don't seem to understand where these resources would be defined in JBoss.  After looking at [the JBoss Community Wiki](http://www.jboss.org/community/wiki/jbossmq), no questions have been answered.  Keep in mind I am new to the whole JMS thing, and relatively new to JBoss.  I did find this [link](http://www.jboss.org/file-access/default/members/jbossmessaging/freezone/docs/usermanual-2.0.0.beta1/html/using-jms.html#using-jms.server.configuration), but that seems to discuss JBossMessaging, which as I understand is a new JMS implementation that is in version JBoss 5, not 4.3.

Our app is deployed as an EAR file with WARs and common library JARs inside it.  Some [further googling](http://codemuch.com/?q=node/80) suggested that I would have to add these definitions to each individual jboss.xml, which I would like to avoid doing.

Basically, I'm confused.  I'm trying to learn JMS while making these changes, but I can't seem to figure this part out.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, EAP 4.3 [does use](http://www.jboss.com/products/platforms/application/components/) JBoss Messaging, just not the 2.0 version that your link references.  You'll want the [documentation for version 1.4.0](http://labs.jboss.com/file-access/default/members/jbossmessaging/freezone/docs/userguide-1.4.0.SP3/html/index.html).